# Why Join Function isn't working when I converted my list to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I expected the output to be 123 using Join function but am not getting the desired result

```
f=['1','2','3']
p=str(f)
k=''.join(p)
print(k)
```

output:
['1', '2', '3']

Comment: Maybe you did it accidentally but you are trying to join the string representation of `f`, not the value of `f`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the call to `str()` here, as the `join()` function is already designed to convert a list into a string.

```
f = ['1','2','3']
k = ''.join(f)
print(k)
```

This prints `123`

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the line `p=str(f)`

`p=str(f)` would return `"['1', '2', '3']"`

```py
f=['1','2','3']
k=''.join(f)
print(k)
# '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

`str(f) == "['1', '2', '3']"`

Don't use `p`:

```
f=['1','2','3']
k=''.join(f)
print(k)
```